# Foreach wont split a string

Tags: c#

```
//assign variables
        string measurementIn;


        //read in file in array
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("../../convert.txt");

        //ask user for date
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the conversion in the form (amount,from,to)");
        measurementIn = Console.ReadLine();

        //array for splitting input
        string[] conversionArray = measurementIn.Split(',');

        Console.WriteLine("{0} , {1} , {2}", conversionArray[0], conversionArray[1], conversionArray[2]);
        Console.ReadLine();

        //check lines for conversion
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            //array for the measurement
            string[] measurementArray = line.Split(',');

            Console.WriteLine("{0}", measurementArray[0]);
```

The problem lies at the end, the stuff inside foreach

Comment: Please describe what you're seeing and what you expected, instead of just posting code.

Comment: What result are you getting? You realise that your code will only print out 1 result per line, and not all split items of that line?

Comment: I am trying to get the line to be split into 3 parts by the comma.
At the moment, nothing is being displayed.

I assume it is possible for this to be done?

Comment: Seems some of the code is missing.  Have you tried to use a less-than symbol?  If so, you will need to edit your question and replace it with '&lt;'.

Comment: Well, are you sure `lines` has anything? Did you try to *debug* this code? It seems simple enough to step trough.

Comment: I have 6 lines in the text file. Basically I am trying to match the first part of the line.Split with the second part of the measurementIn.Split. And if this happpens, I then want to match the second part of the line.Split with the third part of measurementIn.Split

Comment: Did you set breakpoints and tried to debug it? It will print nothing if the file is empty, or the lines start with `","`. Even simpler: write somewhere `Console.WriteLine(lines[0])`. One last thing: you have an extra `Console.ReadLine();` - that can be confusing.

Comment: The file isnt empty, and doesnt start with a ,

Comment: It is working, the file is being read in.,
If i split the lines using foreach, i should get a split for each line. Then how can i view all of this?

Comment: @Luke: Could you edit your question to include your comments. It will make the question easier for people to understand (rather than them having to read through all of the comments). Could you also include the text file you're using (or enough of it to illustrate how it is formatted).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe u search somthing like this?

in Txt:

```
Dog,Cat,Mouse,Fish,Cow,Horse,Hyena
Programmer,Wizard,CEO,Rancher,Clerk,Farmer
```

code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines("TextFile1.txt"))
        {
            string[] parts = line.Split(',');
            foreach (string part in parts)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}",
                    i,
                    part);
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
0:Dog
0:Cat
0:...
1:Programmer
1:...
```

Where i got it:
http://dotnetperls.com/string-split

just tried something:

```
StreamReader convert = new StreamReader("../file.txt");

string line = convert.ReadLine();
String inputMeasurement = Console.ReadLine();
string[] inputMeasurementArray = inputMeasurement.Split(',');
while (line != null)
{
    string[] fileMeasurementArray = line.Split(',');
    if (fileMeasurementArray[0] == inputMeasurementArray[1])
    {
        if (fileMeasurementArray[1] == inputMeasurementArray[2])
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", fileMeasurementArray[2]);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("False");
        }

    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("False");
    }
    line = convert.ReadLine();
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I have 6 lines in the text file. Basically I am trying to match the first part of the line.Split with the second part of the measurementIn.Split. And if this happpens, I then want to match the second part of the line.Split with the third part of measurementIn.Split.

Comment: I have adapted the second part of your code, changed it up and i'm where i need to be. Now got to play around with it to get my final result. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try using a StreamReader to read in lines from the file instead using File.ReadAllLine() and then looping over each line. Like this:

```
StreamReader convert = new StreamReader("filename.txt");

string line = convert.ReadLine();

while (line != null)
{
    string[] measurementArray = line.Split(',');
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", measurementArray[0]);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", measurementArray[1]);
    line = convert.ReadLine();
}
```

You'll need add "using System.IO;".