# looping through a string with foreach

Tags: c#, string, types, foreach, for-in-loop

Okay, so basically I have a string that looks like this:

```
var output = "475183602";
```

and I want to loop through each character in the string.

I currently have this:

```
foreach (char num in output)
    {
     StringBuilder.appendFormat("<p value=\"{0}\"></p>",num);
    }
```

But when I debug, set breakpoints and check the `num` it gives me this:

> 52 '4'

I tried using:

```
foreach (byte num in output)
```

However that just gave me the `52`.

How do I just get the four?

Is it better to run just a for loop like this:

```
for (i=0;i<output.length;i++) {
 var num = output.Substring(i,1);
//string builder here
}
```

or is a foreach loop the way to go?

Comment: `foreach (char num in output.ToCharArray())`...`StringBuilder.appendFormat("<p value=\"{0}\"></p>",num.ToString());`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Foreach wont split a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644165/foreach-wont-split-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the actual contents of the `StringBuilder`, you'll see that it's correct.

Your code is working fine. The debugger is just showing you the ASCII code for the character.

Comment: Yes and No. No, I left out the part where I test whether `num` is equal to another number, so it fails there. Yes, it does work for the string builder.

Comment: @DPB you put the code that does work in your question and left out the bit that you're having problems with?

Answer (score 1):

Your first method is just fine. It gives you 52 because that's the ASCII code for the character '4'. If you want the value of 4, you need to parse the character to a byte value:

```
byte val = byte.Parse(num);
```

Then the variable `val` will have the correct value in it.

Answer (score 1):

try this and it will be fine

```
foreach (char num in output.ToCharArray())
  StringBuilder.AppendFormat("<p value=\"{0}\"></p>",num.ToString());
```